# Para que serve o Membership?

Tags: .net, configuração, web.config, asp.net-membership

Estava analisando o Web.confg e surgiu uma dúvida, qual é a utilidade da tag `membership`? O que ele é?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-aspnet-membership-provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os **providers** Roles e MemberShip fornecem os recursos para gerenciar a autenticação e autorização. Onde a autenticação é o processo para verificar a identidade do usuário e a autorização refere-se ao gerenciamento das permissões dos usuários.

Provedor - Classe Base - Descrição

MemberShip -    MemberShiper - Provider Gerenciar os usuários na aplicação ASP.NET 2.0 - Responsável pela autenticação dos usuários

Roles - RoleProvider - Gerenciar os papeis dos usuários na aplicação ASP.NET 2.0 - Responsável pela autorização com atribuição de grupos e permissões.

Através do provedor MemberShip podemos criar novos usuários e senhas em um banco de dados e validar a identidade do usuário usando a informação armazenada.  Para armazenar a informação o provedor usa um banco de dados SQL Server que é gerado automaticamente, e, de forma transparente na pasta App_Data, se usarmos o modo padrão do provedor.

fonte: http://www.macoratti.net/07/05/aspn_umr.htm